# CSS file wont load

Tags: java, css, jsp

This is my `jsp` page

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: stefa
  Date: 8/26/2021
  Time: 3:24 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/login.css/">


</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
    <div id="formContent">
        <!-- Tabs Titles -->

        <!-- Icon -->
        <div class="fadeIn first">
            <img src="http://danielzawadzki.com/codepen/01/icon.svg" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
        </div>

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="login">
            <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
            <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
        </form>

        <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
        <div id="formFooter">
            <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see how I tried to implement css file

[image: project strcture]

How to fix this? What can I try more? Why my program wont load css file? I also tried to put css in auto created resources folder but still doesnt work

Comment: Since your page is in `resources` as well, did you try `css/login.css`?

Comment: yes, not working, and btw my page isn't in resources

Comment: Having another look at your project structure I see that your CSS files are within WEB-INF. Thus they won't be published at all. Move them out of that folder and then their URL relative to the application's context root should be represented by their path within the application/war file.